# Empty test failling

Tags: javascript, php

I have different span with the **done_by** class and I wanted to know if they are empty or not.

```
$('.done_by').each(function()
    {           
        var emptyTest = $(this).is(':empty');
        console.log(emptyTest);         
    });
```

And I have only '**false**' responses.

However I have the following code when I inspect my page 
[image]

As you can see some are filled and others are empty. But why did I have only **false** responses in my log console ?

I tried with the .length attribute and if else statements but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because [:empty](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) returns false even if there is a text node in the element. So if you create an element like `<span class="done_by"> </span>` then there is an empty text node as its child so it won't be empty. To get an empty node you need `<span class="done_by"></span>`

So in most bases you can use `.has('*')` to see whether it has an element descendant

```
$('.done_by').has('*').each(function() //or $('.done_by:has(*)').each()
{           
    var emptyTest = $(this).is(':empty');
    console.log(emptyTest);         
});
```

Comment: My console does not display anything at all with this solution. It seems that I am not in a standard case.

Moreover, why the standard
$('.done_by').each(function()
  {
   var test = $(this).text();  
   if(test.length <= 1){console.log("ok");}
   else console.log("NOK");
  });

does not work either ?

Comment: @Raccoon can you share a html sample